# data can not get from api in angular

Tags: angular, api

the data that I get from api doesnt show in view. When I dont write *ngFor everything that I put in html tag is show but when I write *ngFor the image or anything that put in html tag is disappear .please help to find problem and sorry for bad English. And is the methods in api service must be have same name with methods in api that writh with django?

**api service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  public APIUrl = "api.trickhub.ir";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSamplesList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/samples');
  }

  getArticlesList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/articles');
  }

  getPlansList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/plans');
  }

  getContactList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/contact');
  }

  getAboutList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/about');
  }

  getArticleDetailsList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/articles/article_detail/id/slug');
  }
}
```

**nemoonekarha.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box d-flex justify-content-center col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-5 mt-5 kl">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active" *ngFor="let item in samples">
            <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**nemoonekarha.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nemoonekarha',
  templateUrl: './nemoonekarha.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nemoonekarha.component.css']
})
export class NemoonekarhaComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }

  public samples: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSamples();
  }

  getSamples() {
    this.service.getSamplesList().subscribe(data => {
      this.samples = data;
    });
  }
}
```

and I add this config

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://api.trickhub.ir",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

and change environment to this

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://api.trickhub.ir'
};
```

but still nothing change and data doesn't show .

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPBAl.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP8Vv.png)

Comment: hi , can you tell me the error that you see in browser console?

Comment: first error : HttpErrorResponse

Comment: second error : Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find it,
You should use "of" instead of "in"  , in your ngFor syntax:

```
*ngFor="let item of samples"
```

in ApiService add "http://" at first of APIUrl like this :

```
export class ApiService {
  public APIUrl = "http://api.trickhub.ir";
```

create a proxy.config.json file like this :

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://api.trickhub.ir",
        "secure": false,        
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

you should set the proxy config in your angular.json settings like  this :

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "your-app-name:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "your-app-name:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: no didn't work.

Comment: this should be for first error !
please comment error full text

Comment: yeah you are right the second error is gone and this is the error message for the first error :Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api.trickhub.ir/samples: 404 Not Found

Comment: add http:// at first of   APIUrl = "api.trickhub.ir"

Comment: no data still don't show.

Comment: and this is new error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.trickhub.ir/samples/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: you should make a proxy config file in your angular project, do you know how define it?

Comment: no unfortunately

Comment: I add something but api still not work

Comment: i update my answer ,follow it

Comment: I did every step that you said but still same problem

Comment: sure? "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json" this is my proxy config file name and place?(my project folder name is "src" and I place proxy.conf.json file there)
Are you sure that you set this ,base on your config file name and its place?
and did you get same error " CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"?

Comment: did you use ng serve?

Comment: the error that I have now is "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/samples: 404 Not Found" that I had before and I put some images in codes ,is that correct and is that what you say about config file name and place?

Comment: no this is a proxy error,you have to set proxy config for call api from a remote server,

Comment: so I did it, I set proxy config but its not working . I don't know why when I write *ngfor in element, the element show nothing but when remove the *ngfor and write something it show in page.

Answer (score 0):

In your component you don't need to declare the variable as public - its typescript so it's implied, instead you would just initialize your variable.  in this case I made it undefined first, so the away allows it time to resolve.  In the advent that it takes longer you might want to add:

setTimeout(()=>{ put your code here}, 1000)

that will create a 1 second wait for the function to complete.

since you are invoking a promise you want to resolve the promise, or await its return.

```
 constructor(private service: ApiService) { }

  samples?:[]=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSamples();
  }

  async getSamples() {
    return this.service.getSamplesList().subscribe(async (data) => {
      return this.samples = await [data];
    });
  }
```

or:

```
samples?:[]=[];
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getSamples();
      }
    
      async getSamples() {
        return this.service.getSamplesList().subscribe(async (sample) => {
          const data = Promise.resolve(await sample);
         return this.samples = [data];
    
    
        });
      }
```